# Por que este código Java retorna 0.0 como divisão entre 7 e 8?

Tags: java, operadores, float

Ao dividir 7 por 8, este código retorna 0.0, por quê?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeiroPrograma {
    static int soma(int a, int b) {
        int sm = a + b;
        return sm;
    }
    static int subtracao(int a, int b) {
        int sub = a - b;
        return sub;
    }
    static int multiplicacao(int a, int b) {
        int mult = a * b;
        return mult;
    }
    static float divisao(int a, int b) {
        float div = (float) (a / b);
        return div;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2, opc;
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite um número: ");
        num1 = ler.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite outro número: ");
        num2 = ler.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("""
                          Digite a operacao desejada: 
                          [1] soma
                          [2] subtracao
                          [3] multiplicao
                          [4] divisao: """);
        opc = ler.nextInt();
        
        
        if(opc == 1) {
            System.out.println("A soma é: "+soma(num1, num2));
        }
        else if(opc == 2) {
            System.out.println("A subtração é: "+subtracao(num1, num2));
        }
        else if(opc == 3) {
            System.out.println("A multiplicação é: "+multiplicacao(num1, num2));
        }
        else if(opc == 4) {
            System.out.println("A divisão é: "+divisao(num1, num2));
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Você usou `int` em num1 e num2, bastava você ter definido como float, assim: `float num1, num2;`, exemplo: https://ideone.com/qG6Wja; isso se for trabalhar com as entradas como int, o float é para as operações aritméticas, se for trabalhar com entradas quebradas, use nextFloat -- Em futuras perguntas siga o modelo [mcve], ao invés de postar o código inteiro. Agradecemos a compreensão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você divide dois inteiros, o resultado é arredondado. Isso está descrito na [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> *Integer division rounds toward 0*

Ou seja, ao dividir 7 por 8, o resultado (`0.875`) é arredondado para o número inteiro `0` (zero).

---

No seu caso, os parênteses fazem toda a diferença. Ao fazer `(float) (a / b)`, primeiro ele faz a conta `a / b`, cujo resultado - como já vimos acima - é zero, e só depois é feito o *cast* do zero para `float`, resultando em `0.0`.

Para funcionar, basta fazer o *cast* de um dos operandos (no seu caso, basta retirar um dos parênteses), ou seja:

```java
// remove os parênteses em volta de "a / b"
float div = (float) a / b;
```

Assim, [primeiro é feito do *cast* de `a` para `float`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464058), e depois este `float` é dividido por `b`. E como agora não é mais uma divisão entre inteiros, o valor não é arredondado, conforme descrito na [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4):

> *If at least one of the operands to a binary operator is of floating-point type, then the operation is a floating-point operation, even if the other operand is integral.*

Ou simplesmente declare os parâmetros como `float`, assim mesmo se você passar inteiros para o método, eles serão tratados como `float`:

```
static float divisao(float a, float b) {
    return a / b;
}
```

---

Apenas um detalhe: não precisa dessas variáveis intermediárias. Se não vai usá-las para mais nada, basta retornar o valor diretamente:

```java
static int soma(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
static int subtracao(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
static int multiplicacao(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
static float divisao(int a, int b) {
    return (float) a / b;
}
```

---

[Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/571760/112052) (que foi apagada) dizia para multiplicar por 1000 a fim de manter o resultado com 3 casas decimais. Só que esta afirmação está completamente errada, pois se testar o código dele com 7 e 9, [o resultado será `0.7777778`](https://ideone.com/1GPtGJ). Se testar com 5 e 10, será `0.5`.

Na verdade aquele código só "funciona" porque ao multiplicar por 1000, ele estava atribuindo o resultado em variáveis do tipo `float` (então ao fazer a divisão não era mais feito o arredondamento). Ou seja, **foi essa atribuição para `float` que "corrigiu" o problema, e não o fato de ter multiplicado por 1000**. Tanto que assim também funcionaria:

```java
static float divisao(int a, int b) {
    float aFloat = a;
    float bFloat = b;
    return aFloat / bFloat;
}
```

Mas acho que as opções que coloquei acima são mais sucintas e direto ao ponto.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Pesquisando na internet encontrei uma solução que acho mais sucinta. Ao invés de definir dois inteiros como parâmetro e dps convertê-los, posso simplesmente passar os parâmetros como float de uma vez só. É mais direto. Fica assim: `static float divisao(float a, float b) {
        return a / b;
       }`

Answer (score -3):

Tenta tirar os colchetes da divisao

static float divisao(int a, int b) {
float div = (float) a / b;
return div;
}